# Automate conversion of special chars to utf-8

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

I have a properties file in this format

attribute1=ó

The problem is I need to convert ó to utf-8 so it can be displayed by java so
ó becomes \u00F3

My properties file becomes -

attribute1=\u00F3

Is there a way to automate this using Java ? In theory to cycle through every character in the file and if a character contains ó (or any non standard ascii character) convert it to its unicode value ?

Or maybe there is a tool out there that already handles this type of conversion ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDK comes bundled with a tool called native2ascii. You will give your properties file as input to the tool and it will perform all the conversion/escaping for you. Look [here](http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/native2ascii-Encoding-Converter-Command-Option.html) for the usage.

However the best option in my opinion is to use the tools like [JRC editor](http://www.zaval.org/products/jrc-editor/). You enter the text in native language and when you save the tool automatically escapes the characters where required

Comment: Thanks for that, why do do you think JRC is a better option ?

Comment: Because 1) you doesn't need to worry about escaping when working the properties file. You are always working in the native language. 2) the tool provides other features like identifying the keys with missing values, duplicates etc

Comment: Or you could use Spring ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource to load those properties, then you can just have that properties file in UTF-8 and no more conversions will be necessary. See http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2009/04/02/utf-8-encoding-and-message-sources/

Comment: correct but that means an external dependency, the reason why i did not specify that option

Comment: JRC editor doesnt seem to be working for me ? How do I perform the converison once I open the properties file ?

Comment: You need to perform any extra steps. you enter the value in the editor and it converts to equivalent unicode codepoint when you save it. And you open the props file again and it does the reverse for you. If you want to really check if this is working then add the native text using the editor, save it and then open the props file using a text editor like notepad++ (my favorite) and you will see the unicode codepoint